# Why is my program erroring (python)?

Tags: python

This code it to simulate merging 2 contact books.

My code errors on line 18 for no apparent reason with a phrase error. I'm pretty sure that the phrasing is correct and that the program should run, but every time I get a phrase error.

```
 class ContactBook:
        """
        This class represents a book of contacts.
        It can store names and phone numbers.
        """

        def __init__(self):
        # Create an empty dictionary
        self.contacts = {}

    def __repr__(self):
        # Just print a string version of the dictionary
        return str(self.contacts)
    def __add__(self, other):
        con2 = ContactBook()
        for name in self.contacts:
            if name in other.contacts and self.contacts[name] != other.contacts[name]:
                con2.contacts[name] = self.contacts[name] + " or " + other.contacts[name]
            else:
                con2.contacts[name] = self.contacts[name]
        for name in other.contacts:
            if name not in self.contacts:
                con2.contacts[name] = other.contacts[names]
        return con2

    def add_contact(self, name, number):
        # Adds a name --> phone number pair to
        # the dictionary.
        self.contacts[name] = number

#############################
# Program starts here

cb1 = ContactBook()
cb2 = ContactBook()

cb1.add_contact("Jonathan", "444-555-6666")
cb1.add_contact("Puneet", "333-555-7777")
cb2.add_contact("Jonathan", "222-555-8888")
cb2.add_contact("Lisa", "111-555-9999")



# The result of this should be a book that
# looks like this:
#
# {
#     "Jonathan": "444-555-6666 or 222-555-8888",
#     "Puneet": "333-555-7777",
#     "Lisa": "111-555-9999"
# }
cb3 = cb1 + cb2
print cb1
print cb2
print cb3
```

Comment: Please share the stack-trace with the error message that you are getting. I never heard of *Phrase Error* in Python. We won't be able to help you without knowing the error

Comment: Your __init__ is not indented correctly

Comment: Works for me once the typos are corrected..

Answer (score 3):

I think `names` is a typo here:

```
con2.contacts[name] = other.contacts[names]
```